# Is there a way to change may keyboard layout before a program opens, and then change it back when the program exits?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, automator, dvorak, qwerty

All without me telling it to do anything after I invoke the fist thing.

I have a mac. And an automator service that changes from dvorak to qwerty before starcraft 2 launches... but is there a way to auto change back to dvorak when I exit starcraft 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know how to do this is to have an applescript "stay open" in the background and detect the application launch/quit.

I used a technique like this [to answer this question](https://superuser.com/questions/143703/is-it-possible-to-somehow-hide-growl-and-herald-when-vlc-runs-fullscreen/155525#155525) about disabling growl while VLC is open. You could adapt it to your situation by detecting if Starcraft is open. When you see it is no longer running, switch the keyboard layout and then quit the applescript.